# Gaining intuition on combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am studying a small section on combinatorics and currently learning about combinations - "$n$ choose $k$." I understand the formula and how we arrive there from the formula for the number of permutations of order $k$ chosen from $n$ distinct objects. However, my understanding and intuition falters when needing to apply this knowledge in a more abstract situation. For example, the book gives an example of the following question: "From a group of $5$ women and $7$ men, how many different committees consisting of $2$ women and $3$ men can be formed? What if $2$ of the men are feuding and refuse to sit on the committee together?"

I understand and was able to do part $1$. However I struggled with how to set up part $2$ and eventually ended up looking at the solution that the example gave. The solution is as follows.

> The number of committees that don't include the $2$ men together are $$C(7,3) - C(2,2) C(5,1) = 30$$ etc...

There's obviously more to the solution but this is the part I struggle to see. This was the very first example after the formula for a combination was given so I want to try and gain as much intuition as I can. Breaking down this equation I know that $C(7,3)$ is the number of combinations of $3$ men from the given $7$ men (without reference to order). Hence it seems to me that $C(2,2)C(5,1)$ would represent the number of committees in which the $2$ men are serving together. I am having trouble with $2$ facets of this solution:

1. Seeing how $C(2,2)C(5,1)$ represents the number of committees with both feuding men serving together
2. Being able to come up with this myself. How should one approach a problem like this? How would you think about setting up and approaching a problem like this?

Comment: $C(2,2)C(5,1)$ is the number of ways to have two chosen from the two feuding men and one chosen from five other men.

Comment: You have to learn by practice. Sometimes you directly get a solution, sometimes you need to add different committees in "at least..." type problems, sometimes you need to subtract out "bad" committees as in this problem.

Comment: The art of combinatorics is the art of splitting a complex problem in simple problems.You need to find intermediate questions, that you are able to answer. How many ways to choose 3 men in 5, when 2 are mandatory. 2 are mandatory, so the question is How many ways to choose 1 remaining man in the 5 remaining men. Answer is simple, it is 5. It was written C(5,1), but I definitely prefer 5.  Similar, C(2,2) is correct, but I prefer 1. We MULTIPLY C(2,2) by C(5,5), because for each choice in 1st group (only 1 choice !), we have 5 options in the 2nd group.

Comment: @Lourrran I understand now. Since the term being subtracted is all groups of $3$ men that include the $2$ who are feuding then to form such a group requires $2$ steps. The first of which is choosing $2$ men who are feuding out of the group of incompatible group of men (total $2$) and then the second step required to fill such a group is to choose $1$ more man out of the $5$ remaining men. Is it often safe to assume when dealing with counting/combinatorics problems that multiplication of terms can be viewed as steps in a process where it term represents the number of choices in that step?

Comment: It is more than often, it is always. If you have to choose 5 cards in a 52 cards' game, and you want to calculate how many results will contain exactly 2 spades, you will count the number of possibilities to select 2 spades among 13 C(13,2), then count the number of possibilities to select 3 cards in the remaining 39 cards C(39,3), and finally multiply $C(13,2) \times C(39,3)$

Comment: Even better! Thanks for the help @Lourrran.